# Sencha Touch Sync and Get New Data from Server

Tags: sencha-touch, store, synchronization, overwrite

My app is a list of ToDo's of forms that need to be completed.

1. When the app is opened, it goes to the server and collects (from a database) a list of forms to be completed.
2. When you click on a form you can then fill in the data (using LocalStorage proxy) and then save/update the data. The data is stored locally on the device.

As of now : When I open the app again, it collects the same list of ToDo's and overwrites the data in the LocalStorage (ie my filled up forms) with new empty forms and therefore I need to fill them again.

What I want : Instead of overwriting filled up forms I need to only collect those forms that are not already in my localstorage.

My Code : 
Store :-
Code:

```
FMS.stores.onlineTodo =  new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'ToDoMod',
proxy: {
    id : 'fmsonlinetodo',
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'app/data/dummydata.json',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'items'
    }),
    timeout: 2000,
    listeners: {
        exception:function () {
            console.log("I think we are offline");
            flagoffline = 1;
//              
        }
    }
 }
});

FMS.stores.offlineTodo = new Ext.data.Store({
model : 'ToDoMod',
proxy : {
    type : 'localstorage',
    id : 'fmsofflinetodo'
}
});
```

Controller function that loads data into store :

Code:

```
loadDataInitial : function(){

    FMS.stores.onlineTodo.addListener('load', function () {
        console.log("I think we are online");
        FMS.stores.offlineTodo.proxy.clear();
        FMS.stores.onlineTodo.each(function (record) {                         
              FMS.stores.offlineTodo.add(record.data)[0];
        });
        FMS.stores.offlineTodo.sync();
        FMS.stores.offlineTodo.load();
        flagoffline = 0;
    });

    if(flagoffline == 0){
        FMS.stores.onlineTodo.load();
    }
    else{
        FMS.stores.offlineTodo.load();
    }


},
```

HELP !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are clearing all of your localStorage records when you use this:

```
FMS.stores.offlineTodo.proxy.clear();
```

What you would want to do is use the online store to collect all of the database records and then for each record, query local storage for the same record and if it exists, don't update it.

Basically a version control approach but definitely don't clear the store, you will delete everything in it!

UPDATED:

Here is some sample code:

```
//load remotestore
remoteStore.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        //get record count
        var localCount = localStore.getCount();

        if (localCount == 0) {
            //iterate each record in remotestore
            remoteStore.each(function (record) {
                //add record to localStorage
                localStore.add(record.copy());
            });

            //save localstore
            localStore.sync();

        } else {
            //set count var
            var count = 0;

            //iterate each record in remotestore
            remoteStore.each(function (record) {
                //reset var
                var localRecord = null;
                //find matching record in localstore
                localRecord = localStore.findRecord('xid', record.data.xid, null, false, false, true);

                //if the record exists
                if (localRecord) {
                    //version check
                    if (record.data.version > localRecord.data.version) {
                        //remove record from localstore and add new one
                        localStore.remove(localRecord);
                        localStore.add(record.copy());
                        //increment counter
                        ++count;
                    }
                } else {
                    //add record to localstore
                    localStore.add(record);
                }
            });

            //save localstore
            if (localStore.sync()) {
                alert("store saved");
            }

            //if records were added we need to reload
            if (count > 0) {
                this.onUpdate();// or whatever your function is.
            }
        }
      }
    });  //ends
```

Comment: How do I do that ?? Im not sure how to query for the same record to see if it exists... Could you gimme some sample code or examples pls ??

Comment: Give me a day to try this, and get back to you on whether it worked :) Grazie (in advance)

Comment: @SashaZd note that this code was used for ST2.0 and could be simplified and improved. For example, you would likely want to work with a model instance instead of directly on the store. Also consider whether or not the model has any associations because this code does not. :)

Answer (score 0):

in your store's load method, just pass addRecords:true, like so:

```
FMS.stores.onlineTodo.load({addRecords: true});
```